# Can I use 3D People or Renderpeople and place them on Blender?

Tags: rendering

For resources that provide digital humans like Renderpeople and 3D People, can Blender utilize these resources? I wanted to know if I can animate them myself.

Comment: Yes, you can, either with the builtin .obj importer or directly with the .blend file which they sometimes provide on their assets.

Comment: Thank You! I will take this into account once I buy the resources!

Comment: IIRC they have a few free resources you can test beforehand, one of them is already rigged and animated (a woman)